# visual studio change dynamic linking to static linking for win32 app

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dynamic, static-linking

the app is already created with dynamic configuration

anybody knows how to change dynamic linking to static linking for win32 app ?
Note: just changing

> `Properties` -> `Configuration Properties` -> `C/C++` -> `Code Generation`

gives an linking error

thanks for all help

Answer (score 2):

On the Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation

Setting 'Runtime Library' from Multi-threaded (/MT) to Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd) worked for me so the msvcr100.dll was no longer required because it is built into the exe.  Thus static linking is enabled.

I did not get any linking error.  What is the error you got?